# Github CSV pull conversion

Tags: python, github

I'm having issues converting the pulled CSV data from GitHub

```
r = requests.get(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}'.format(
        owner=owner, repo=repo, path=path),
    headers={
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
        'authorization': 'token {}'.format(token)
    }
)

f = open("myfile.txt", 'w')
f.write(r.text)
f.close()

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

I would like to convert the data back to a CSV without using Pandas, as for some reason, my data is read incorrectly if I do. The above script does the job but it involves creating a text file and converting it to a CSV file. Although it works, it looks inelegant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your data directly to a CSV file, just parse your data to be something clear like an array of objects and each object will represent the record in CSV, Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37382942/15408628)